# Excel: How to combine all cells in a column, separated by commas?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with 100+ entries. One column consists of IDs. I need to combine these into a single string with each ID separated by a comma, eg:

### | ID |

|123|
|567|
|890|

Becomes one cell with the value

```
123,567,980
```

I know I can `concat` each cell, but there are hundreds.

Is there a way I can concat the entire column, but separate it by commas?

Closes I've gotten is:

```
=CONCAT(A:A)
```

but I can't figure out how to add a separator so it just outputs:

```
123567980
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) :

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:A3)
' Output : 123,456,789
```

[image]

Or with a custom function using VBA :

```
=ConcatWithSep(A1:A3,",")

Function ConcatWithSep(Ref As Range, Sep As String) As String

Dim Row As Range
Dim Output As String

For Each Row In Ref
Output = Output & Row.Value & Sep
Next Row

ConcatWithSep = Left(Output, Len(Output) - 1)

End Function
```

Another solution with PowerQuery using [`Table.Transpose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/powerquery-m/table-transpose) and [`Table.CombineColumns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/powerquery-m/table-combinecolumns) :

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Changed Type"),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Transposed Table", {{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}}, "en-US"),{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged")
in
    #"Merged Columns"
```

Answer (score 3):

TEXTJOIN function is a better alternative.
You can add a separator within double quotes, for example, ","

So as per your problem, you can write the formula as

```
=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, starting cell: end cell)
```